# Nice dimension independent proof of entropy inequality?

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, entropy

How does one prove that for arbitrary finite number of random variables $X,Y,Z,T,...$ the Shannon Entropy inequality holds

$H(X,Y,Z,T,...) \leq H(X)+H(Y)+H(Z)+H(T)+...$

I know how to do it with Lagrange multipliers, but I was wondering if there is something more tidy out there

Comment: This inequality directly follows from the entropy [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule) and the fact that [conditioning reduces entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Other_properties).

Comment: Oh, I see, Jensen's Inequality -> Log-sum inequality -> Conditioning reduces entropy. My question is thus almost equivalent to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704452/alternative-proof-that-conditioning-reduces-entropy)